# Instance metadata on IBM Cloud

Tags: exploit, audit, cloud-computing, kubernetes

Is there any way to get instance metadata on IMB Cloud (a.k.a Bluemix) K8s cluster, from a compromised pod?

Something like doing `curl` to `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/...` on GKE clusters, or `http://169.254.169.254/latest/...` on EKS clusters.